# abstract interface methods in C# 8 preview

Tags: c#, c#-8.0, default-interface-member

I try:

```
public interface I { abstract void F(); }
```

I get:

> The modifier 'abstract' is not valid for this item in C# 7.3. Please
>   use language version 'preview' or greater.

However I can find no mention of this feature ie in https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/whats-new/csharp-8

Where can I find the docs for that ? or is the message wrong here ?

Comment: The message says "in C# 7.3." The document you are referring is about C# 8.0

Comment: the msg says not avail in 7.3 and suggests it is avail in 8.0 preview

Comment: Did you switch your project over to using language version preview?

Comment: no, I don't want to do this ATM, just curious what would abstract interface method mean ?

Comment: I think it's missing from that page you linked just because it's not implemented yet (or wasn't when that page was published). There's tons of articles about the proposed feature though. Just google "c# abstract interface".

Comment: The docs should get updated with "default interface members" feature in the next couple weeks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

C# 8.0 will allow modifiers and default implementations for interface members. You can see discussion [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/issues/288) and details [here](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md)

However, the `abstract` modifier in an interface method makes zero sense IMO, but it might be available in the C# 8, since other modifiers will be valid as well.

You can see the `abstract` is listed in the [allowed modifiers](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/default-interface-methods.md#modifiers-in-interfaces)

> The syntax for an interface is relaxed to permit modifiers on its members. The following are permitted: private, protected, internal, public, virtual, **abstract**, sealed, static, extern, and partial.

Comment: The use _might_ be to to re-abstract a method further down an interface hierarchy after a default implementation was added higher up to force implementing classes to implement the method as well, instead of taking the default.

Comment: so what will happen if I upgrade to c# 8 preview - it will just compile and do nothing ?

Comment: yes, in your example `abstract` should make no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Like the other answer it is legal from c#8.0.
But is there any benefit of having abstract methods in interface??

With recent improvements in the language, `abstract` function in interface can be considered as something which will not have default implementation.

Now the C# interfaces can have default implementation for interface functions. Look at the below example. It is totally fine and the output is "Default implemented example function".

```
//AN INTERFACE WITH DEFUALT METHOD
interface I
{
  string Example()
  {
      return "Default implemented example function";
  }
}

//CLASS IMPLEMENTING THE INTERFACE
class C : I
{

}

//AN EXAMPLE CLASS ACCESSING THE DEFAULT IMPLEMENTED example FUNCTION.
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I i = new C();
        Console.WriteLine (i.Example());
    }
}
```

In the above example lets suppose try adding `abstract` for the "Example()" function in Interface.

The code **will not** compile saying "'I.Example()' cannot declare a body because it is marked abstract"

So when we use `abstract` the obvious way is to define the function in the class (implements interface) for any usage(shown below).

```
//AN INTERFACE WITH ABSTRACT METHOD
interface I
{
  abstract string Example();
}

//CLASS IMPLEMENTING THE INTERFACE AND GIVE A BODY FOR EXAMPLE FUNCTION
class C : I
{
    public string Example()
    {
        return "Implemented example function";
    }

}

//A CLASS ACCESSING THE CLASS METHOD EXAMPLE.
public class Test
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        I i = new C();
        Console.WriteLine (i.Example());
    }
}
```

In summary declaring the function in interface as `abstract`, there can not be a default body for the function in interface, instead the class implements the interface must have a body for it.